# Assume that the double sequence $(a_{m,n})_{m,n}$ converges to $0$. Then is the set $\left \{ a_{m,n}:m,n\in\mathbb{N} \right \}$ bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

> Assume that the double sequence $(a_{m,n})_{m,n}$ converges to $0$. Then is the set $\left \{ a_{m,n}:m,n\in\mathbb{N} \right \}$ bounded?

Is the set is not bounded because the set is for all $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$, and not for all $m,n\geq N\in \mathbb{N}$? Does a counterexample work to prove this statement is wrong?

Comment: Yes, a counterexample disproves it. Do you have a counterexample? If so, you should include it in your post!

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry, I did not create one!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align*}
(a_{1,1},a_{1,2},a_{1,3},a_{1,4},...)&=(1,1/2,1/3,1/4,...)\\
(a_{2,1},a_{2,2},a_{2,3},a_{2,4},...)&=(2,1/2,1/3,1/4,...)\\
(a_{3,1},a_{3,2},a_{3,3},a_{3,4},...)&=(3,1/2,1/3,1/4,...)\\
\vdots
\end{align*}
The sequence $\{a_{m,n}\}$ tends to $0$ as $m,n\rightarrow\infty$ but it is not bounded, as can be seen in the first column of the above arrays.

Comment: Do you have any specific double sequence that does this?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question?

Comment: @numericalorange They gave an explicit example...

Comment: Do you have a specific example of a double sequence converging to zero yet the set is not bounded?

Comment: The philosophy is that, the compliment of $m,n\geq N$ is NOT $m,n\leq N$, I did a mistake just now and thanks to @spaceisdarkgreen for pointing out the issue. Rather, the compliment would contain the case like, fixing a column not beyond $N$ but varying through the rows, and this is how I get the counterexample done.

Comment: Oh I see. Did you use the Harmonic sequence?

Comment: Harmonic sequence means $1,1/2,1/3,...$? If so, yes, in some sense I used that.

Comment: I want to use $\frac{1}{mn}$ as counterexample. Would it be correct?

Comment: If $a_{m,n}=\dfrac{1}{mn}$ for all $m,n$, then apparently this is bounded by $1$, not unbounded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72745/discussion-between-numericalorange-and-user284331).

Comment: @user284331 Sorry to bother you again, but what if say, instead of 1, 2, 3 as your first column, it was -1, 1, -1, 1 and so on? Would this still count as unbounded?

Comment: No, it is bounded, because then the absolute value of the entries in such a first column is bounded by $1$.

Comment: @user284331 I used $a_{m,n}=\frac{m}{n}$ as counterexample and it seems to be working?

Comment: But $m/n$ does not converge as a double sequence.

Comment: @user284331 I cannot seem to find a good counterexample, because they all seem to fail. What about $a_{m,n}=\frac{cosn}{m}$?

Comment: Actually mine is a counterexample. The $\dfrac{\cos n}{m}$ is bounded.

Comment: @numericalorange  What is wrong with the example in this answer?

Comment: I guess it was hard for me to understand the given counterexample, since it's defined very explicitly (makes me doubt myself, I am just a beginner in this type of math)... but thank you for your troubles in helping me, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @user284331 May I ask what you mean by fixing a column not beyond $N$? Do you mean the column for $m,n$ or do you mean the $1,2,3,...$ column?

Comment: Do you know the matrix? I am using the matrix notion of column, I should say, $N$th column.

Comment: The elements of my so called $N$th column are $a_{1,N},a_{2,N},a_{3,N},...$